# ActionListener created through EventHandler not working

Tags: java, swing, exception, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public class event {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sframe frame = new Sframe();
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class Sframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Sframe() {
        Spanel panel = new Spanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.buttonadd();
        //panel.buttonadd();
    }
}

class Spanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public void buttonadd() {
        javax.swing.JButton blackb = new JButton("Black");
        add(blackb);
        blackb.addActionListener((ActionListener)EventHandler
        .create(ActionListener.class,this,"hello"));
    }
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("I love every girl");
    }
    static int i;
}
```

When i am clicking on black button it throws following error. I am following Core Java book.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No method called hello on class Spanel with no arguments
at java.beans.EventHandler.invokeInternal(EventHandler.java:476)
at java.beans.EventHandler.access$000(EventHandler.java:278)
```

I have skipped many lines in the error...its a long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, the target class is required to be `public`. Reflection is used under the hood by `EventHandler` and has the limitation of only being able to use `public` classes for finding the target method.

```
public class Spanel {
```

Comment: yeah its working...but any reason ..why this require Spanel to be public .

Comment: This is a requirement due to the use of reflection by the `EventHandler`. See update.